# Rails 6 mysubdomain.lvh.me redirected you too many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails 6 App with subdomains (sort of a multi-tenant approach but not using separate schemas).

I am trying to build a before_action that i can set on my application controller to assess wether there is an account that matches the request.subdomain call when a user lands on the site.

for example,

a member of hammer corp wants to go login they would proceed to hammer.lvh.me when that request is made I want my before filter to see that the request matches an exsisting account and says coolio and redirect them to their respective login page. If no account matches a subdomain (ie a typo) i want them to be redirected to my root_url or signup page.

I currently have this

```
def verify_account!
  if @account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain).present?
    redirect_to login_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
  else
    redirect_to root_url(subdomain: nil)
  end
end
```

When I try to hit the site with a valid subdoamin I can indeed see it wants to redirect me to the login page in the url, however I get the `redirected you too many times` in my browser.

Not too sure how to proceed to fix this? any assistance would be great!

**EDIT # 1 - Full application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :verify_account!
  # before_action :set_account

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end

  private

    def verify_account!
      if @account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain).present?
        redirect_to login_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
      else
        redirect_to root_url(subdomain: nil)
      end
    end

    # def require_account!
      # redirect_to root_url(subdomain: nil) if !@account.present?
      # flash[:error] = "An account is required to access this page. Please sign up or proceed to your_company.loadze.co to login"
    # end

    def set_account
      @account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
      # byebug
    end

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:f_name, :l_name, account_attributes: [:company_name]])
    end

end
```

**EDIT # 2: Adds Server Output**

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-30 04:29:16 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "tauren_group"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:17:in `verify_account!'
Redirected to http://tauren_group.lvh.me:3000/login
Filter chain halted as :verify_account! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 865)
```

Comment: Can we see the full sessions controller please

Comment: @Mark standard devise sessions controller this is being handled in the application controller

Comment: Are there any before_actions being hit? Your app is obviously redirecting multiple times and only one of the redirects in the method you pasted can be hit, so there must be another being invoked somewhere

Comment: @Mark Ive updated the question with the full contents of the application controller

Comment: ahh the method itself is a before_action - try changing line 2 of the method to `return redirect_to login_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)` - that should stop the second redirect firing

Comment: @Mark still getting the too many redirects with the return added

Comment: hmm... after your verify_account method redirects, does the method fire again and keep on redirecting? Sorry I'm out of ideas after that

Comment: @Mark It looks like it only fires once, i added the server output for the request it spits out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is redirected to the login screen, it is redirected again because it is entering to if block again. Try this:

```
def verify_account!
  if @account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain).present?
    return if request.url == login_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)

    redirect_to login_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
  else
    redirect_to root_url(subdomain: nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: this works exactly, however it works too well lol.. i cant do a single thing in my app because that block fires on every action as its a before_action in my application controller.. would you have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Add `return if current_user.present?` to `verify_account!` method. `def verify_account! return if current_user.present? if ..`.  I'm not sure, it can solve the problem.

Comment: better way: `before_action :verify_account!, if: proc { current_user.blank? }`